# PDO Inserir Registro

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com problemas ao ***inserir*** registro no banco com `PDO`, abaixo segue a `tabela` e `script`:

***tabela calendar***

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `enddate` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `allDay` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

***conexao.php***

```
<?php
try {
    // Faz Conexão com o banco de dados
    $conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=wsphp","root","");   
} catch (PDOException $e) {
// Caso ocorra algum erro com a conexção com o banco, exibe a mensagem
    echo 'Falha ao conectar com o banco de dados: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
}  

<?php

include_once "conexao.php";
try {
    $titulo = filter_var($_POST['titulo']); // Evita o sql injection
    $start = filter_var($_POST['start']); // Evita o sql injection
    $end = filter_var($_POST['end']); // Evita o sql injection
    $allDay = filter_var($_POST['allDay']);; // Evita o sql injection

    $sql = "INSERT INTO title, startdate, enddate VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :allDay)";
    $insert = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $insert->bindParam(':title', $titulo); // Evita o SQL Injection
    $insert->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $insert->bindParam(':end', $end);
    $insert->bindParam(':allDay', $allDay);
    $conectar->beginTransaction();    
    $insert->execute();
    $conectar->commit();

    //header('location: index.php');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Erro: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na estrutura da tabela o **id** não está definido como auto incremento e está definido com **NOT NULL** isso faz com ele seja obrigatório na hora da inserção,ou seja não pode ser nulo. Para corrigir isso defina o **id** como **auto incremento**  e como **chave primaria**, com isso você não vai precisar passar ele na inserção pois ele vai ser auto incrementado pelo próprio banco. pode ver a referencia mais detalhada nesse link
[SQL AUTO INCREMENT Field](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

SQL da table seria assim

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `id` int(11) INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `enddate` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `allDay` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Já no SQL inserção está faltando o nome da tabela e coluna allday que também está  definido como não nulo ou seja é obrigatório, código deveria ser assim:

```
INSERT INTO calendar(title, startdate, enddate, allDay)  VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :allDay);
```

pode saber mais sobre INSERT nesse link [The SQL INSERT INTO Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

No seu  código parece que você teve problemas com as colunas **NOT NULL** 
veja esse link para saber mais sobre [SQL NOT NULL Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp)

Seria uma boa praticá usar o tipo **date** nas colunas de data,
se tiver dificuldades de manipular dadas com php pode usar biblioteca com 
[Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

Comment: Muito Obigrado @Dejair Sisconeto. Realmente foi uma total falta de atenção. Funcionou.....

Comment: Por nada ;) agora é só marca a resposta com a certa

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**Se está com qualquer problema, relate o problema colocando isso na sua pergunta, uma tela de erros ajude bastante para solucionar problemas desse tipo**</sup>

***Isso:***

```
INSERT INTO title, startdate, enddate VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :allDay)
```

***deveria ser isso***

```
INSERT INTO calendar(title, startdate, enddate, allDay) 
             VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :allDay);
```

ou seja, não foi especificado o nome da tabela e os campos corretamente sua [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) esta com problemas.

***Observações:***

- a primeira `SQL` estava faltando passar também o `allDay`.
- se `startdate` e `enddate` forem ***datas***, deveria mudar o tipo para [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) na sua tabela, nunca trabalhe com tipos diferentes do que precisa, além de dar problemas em conversões e filtro.
- o campo `id` pelo que pude perceber deve ser [auto_incremento](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html), tem que modificar esse campo na sua tabela, se não sua `SQL` vai dar outro erro, porque, o `id` é obrigatório como os demais campos.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/)
- [12.7 Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)
- [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

Comment: muito obrigado. Realmente uma falha grotesca minha. Funcionou.